# openCV 'cvPoint' and 'CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX' not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ros, catkin

I'm trying to get the [LSD-SLAM](https://github.com/kevin-george/lsd_slam) by Kevin George. 
But I got stuck because openCV doesn't want to be cooperative and when using `catkin_make` it doesn't know the following two things.

```
/home/adas/ros_workspace/src/src/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src/util/globalFuncs.cpp: In function ‘void lsd_slam::printMessageOnCVImage(cv::Mat&, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’:
/home/adas/ros_workspace/src/src/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src/util/globalFuncs.cpp:52:28: error: ‘cvPoint’ was not declared in this scope
  cv::putText(image, line2, cvPoint(10,image.rows-5),
                            ^~~~~~~
/home/adas/ros_workspace/src/src/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src/util/globalFuncs.cpp:52:28: note: suggested alternative: ‘cvRound’
  cv::putText(image, line2, cvPoint(10,image.rows-5),
                            ^~~~~~~
                            cvRound
```

and

```
/home/adas/ros_workspace/src/src/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src/util/globalFuncs.cpp:53:6: error: ‘CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX’ was not declared in this scope
      CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, cv::Scalar(200,200,250), 1, 8);
```

in case of the cvPoint catkin_make suggests replacing the **cvPoint** with **cvRount** which doesn't work as then I get a new error that the funciton with that type can't be found.

Here is be the full source code if it would help you.

```
/**
* This file is part of LSD-SLAM.
*
* Copyright 2013 Jakob Engel <engelj at in dot tum dot de> (Technical University of Munich)
* For more information see <http://vision.in.tum.de/lsdslam> 
*
* LSD-SLAM is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
* (at your option) any later version.
*
* LSD-SLAM is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with LSD-SLAM. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#include "util/globalFuncs.h"
#include "util/SophusUtil.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "DataStructures/Frame.h"

namespace lsd_slam
{


SE3 SE3CV2Sophus(const cv::Mat &R, const cv::Mat &t)
{
    Sophus::Matrix3f sR;
    Sophus::Vector3f st;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        sR(0,i) = R.at<double>(0,i);
        sR(1,i) = R.at<double>(1,i);
        sR(2,i) = R.at<double>(2,i);
        st[i] = t.at<double>(i);
    }

    return SE3(toSophus(sR.inverse()), toSophus(st));
}

void printMessageOnCVImage(cv::Mat &image, std::string line1,std::string line2)
{
    for(int x=0;x<image.cols;x++)
        for(int y=image.rows-30; y<image.rows;y++)
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) *= 0.5;

    cv::putText(image, line2, cvPoint(10,image.rows-5),
        CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, cv::Scalar(200,200,250), 1, 8);

    cv::putText(image, line1, cvPoint(10,image.rows-18),
        CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, cv::Scalar(200,200,250), 1, 8);
}


cv::Mat getDepthRainbowPlot(Frame* kf, int lvl)
{
    return getDepthRainbowPlot(kf->idepth(lvl), kf->idepthVar(lvl), kf->image(lvl),
            kf->width(lvl), kf->height(lvl));
}

cv::Mat getDepthRainbowPlot(const float* idepth, const float* idepthVar, const float* gray, int width, int height)
{
    cv::Mat res = cv::Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3);
    if(gray != 0)
    {
        cv::Mat keyFrameImage(height, width, CV_32F, const_cast<float*>(gray));
        cv::Mat keyFrameImage8u;
        keyFrameImage.convertTo(keyFrameImage8u, CV_8UC1);
        cv::cvtColor(keyFrameImage8u, res, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    }
    else
        fillCvMat(&res,cv::Vec3b(255,170,168));

    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
        {
            float id = idepth[i + j*width];

            if(id >=0 && idepthVar[i + j*width] >= 0)
            {

                // rainbow between 0 and 4
                float r = (0-id) * 255 / 1.0; if(r < 0) r = -r;
                float g = (1-id) * 255 / 1.0; if(g < 0) g = -g;
                float b = (2-id) * 255 / 1.0; if(b < 0) b = -b;

                uchar rc = r < 0 ? 0 : (r > 255 ? 255 : r);
                uchar gc = g < 0 ? 0 : (g > 255 ? 255 : g);
                uchar bc = b < 0 ? 0 : (b > 255 ? 255 : b);

                res.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = cv::Vec3b(255-rc,255-gc,255-bc);
            }
        }
    return res;
}
cv::Mat getVarRedGreenPlot(const float* idepthVar, const float* gray, int width, int height)
{
    float* idepthVarExt = (float*)Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc(width*height*sizeof(float));

    memcpy(idepthVarExt,idepthVar,sizeof(float)*width*height);

    for(int i=2;i<width-2;i++)
        for(int j=2;j<height-2;j++)
        {
            if(idepthVar[(i) + width*(j)] <= 0)
                idepthVarExt[(i) + width*(j)] = -1;
            else
            {
                float sumIvar = 0;
                float numIvar = 0;
                for(int dx=-2; dx <=2; dx++)
                    for(int dy=-2; dy <=2; dy++)
                    {
                        if(idepthVar[(i+dx) + width*(j+dy)] > 0)
                        {
                            float distFac = (float)(dx*dx+dy*dy)*(0.075*0.075)*0.02;
                            float ivar = 1.0f/(idepthVar[(i+dx) + width*(j+dy)] + distFac);
                            sumIvar += ivar;
                            numIvar += 1;
                        }
                    }
                idepthVarExt[(i) + width*(j)] = numIvar / sumIvar;
            }

        }


    cv::Mat res = cv::Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3);
    if(gray != 0)
    {
        cv::Mat keyFrameImage(height, width, CV_32F, const_cast<float*>(gray));
        cv::Mat keyFrameImage8u;
        keyFrameImage.convertTo(keyFrameImage8u, CV_8UC1);
        cv::cvtColor(keyFrameImage8u, res, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    }
    else
        fillCvMat(&res,cv::Vec3b(255,170,168));

    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
        {
            float idv = idepthVarExt[i + j*width];

            if(idv > 0)
            {
                float var= sqrt(idv);

                var = var*60*255*0.5 - 20;
                if(var > 255) var = 255;
                if(var < 0) var = 0;

                res.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = cv::Vec3b(0,255-var, var);
            }
        }

    Eigen::internal::aligned_free((void*)idepthVarExt);

    return res;
}
}
```

Here is also some information what I have installed, that I thing might be helpful:

- openCV 4.1.1-pre
- ROS Melodic
- Ubuntu 18.04
- CMake 3.10.2
- CatKin_tools 0.4.5
- Python 3.6.8

Hope someone out there is able to help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't mix the obsolete C api with the C++ api.
Use `cv::Point` instead of `cvPoint`, and `cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX` instead of `CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX`, e.g.:

```
cv::putText(image, line1, cv::Point(10,image.rows-18),
        cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, cv::Scalar(200,200,250), 1, 8);
```

Comment: ah ok... Makes sense.
Thank you